# How can I transfer Mysql data to another computer and add it to an exist database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to transfer Mysql data to another computer and add it to an exist database

Here is the condition:
1. Computer A, A has a database named 'Test';
2. Computer B, B has a database named 'Formal';
3. Test and Formal have exactly the same tables and fields.
4. I use A to get new data and add the data to B.
5. Remote connection to B's MySQL is forbidden.

Here is how I deal with it now:
1. Create a 'Transfer' database in B;
2. Dump Source's data into test.sql;
3. Copy test.sql to B;
4. Backup Formal database;
5. Source test.sql to Transfer database.
6. Use a script to take Transfer's data and add to Target.

I am wondering if I can add Test's data into Formal database directly?

I am not a native English speaker and fresh new in MySQL, so if there is any confusion upthere, please tell me and i'll try my best to make it clear.

Comment: Is this a Read-Write -splitting case?

Comment: this command should do the task for you - `mysqldump -h oldhost -u oldusername -poldpassword olddbname | mysql -h newhost -u newusername -pnewpassword newdbname`

Comment: @Murtaza: Remote connection to computer B is forbidden. But i am now working on mysqldump to see if i can do something else with it. Thanks!

Comment: @heikkim: I don't know exactly what 'Read-Write -splitting' is, but i don't think it is.

Comment: How do you do *"3. Copy test.sql to B;"* if you have no remote access to B? Copy the test.sql to a USB stick, then ship the stick to location B?

Comment: @ypercube: Sorry, remote access to B's MySQL is forbidden.

Comment: So, I ask it again. How are you dealing with it now? How do you get anything to B? Do you have physical access to both machines?

Answer (score 0):

In MySql you can it import it in the GUI

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/images/screenshots/users.png

there you can import and export it with a data.sql

or you you save the data from A in an dataset and then you update the dataset in the b database or other around so you have copy the database B to A

p.s. admins pls put the image in i cant do it

p.s.billy i explained it with the image